# How to subtract time using PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to subtract one array to another array. but this is related to time. I am unable to produce expected output. Simply I just want to remove  2nd array overlap time slot from the first array.

I have the following array as an example

```
$array1 = [
            0 => [
                'start_hour' => 9,
                'start_minute' => 0,
                'end_hour' => 12,
                'end_minute' => 0
            ],
            1 => [
                'start_hour' => 13,
                'start_minute' => 0,
                'end_hour' => 18,
                'end_minute' => 0
            ]
        ];

 $array2 = [
            'start_hour' => 11,
            'start_minute' => 0,
            'end_hour' => 11,
            'end_minute' => 30
        ];
```

Now i want to subtract $array2 from $array1.

My expected output like below:

```
 $result = [
            0 => [
                'start_hour' => 9,
                'start_minute' => 0,
                'end_hour' => 11,
                'end_minute' => 0
            ],
            1 => [
                'start_hour' => 11,
                'start_minute' => 30,
                'end_hour' => 12,
                'end_minute' => 0
            ],
            2 => [
                'start_hour' => 13,
                'start_minute' => 0,
                'end_hour' => 18,
                'end_minute' => 0
            ]
        ];
```

Any solutions or kind of clue would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if the time period in array2 doesn't overlap any of those in array1?

Comment: While you may be able to muddle through for one specific case, a generalised solution would probably involve an [Interval Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).

Comment: The easiest way to play with time differences is to store and manage the results of `time()` and `microtime(true)`. use subtract for differences. Convert it to text only on output for the user.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This looks like a perfect dummy project to learn TDD